# Javascript: thinks an input field is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a legacy web app trying to make some old IE-centric code browser portable, and have hit a problem I don't quite understand.

Here is a snippet of the HTML I'm looking at

```
<INPUT ID="H_Documents" NAME="H_Documents" TYPE=hidden VALUE="off"/>
<TD ID="B_Documents" CLASS=menuoff NOWRAP WIDTH=11% VALIGN=CENTER onClick="if(document.readyState=='complete')expandMenu(T_Documents,B_Documents,H_Documents)" TITLE="Click to Show/Hide Documents" onmouseover="tabhiliteon(this)" onmouseout="tabhiliteoff(this)">
  Documents
</TD>
```

On all current browsers this works fine, in that a click on the text "Documents" calls expandMenu and the 3rd parameter is avialable in the function, apart from in IE when *not* in compatibility mode, where it refuses to call expandMenu and complains that H_documents is undefined.

Can somebody give me a clue :)

Thanks

Comment: Which IE version/s do you have problems with?

Comment: That's not valid HTML.

Comment: In versions of Internet Explorer prior to IE8, getElementById() does a case-insensitive match on element IDs and also returns elements that have a matching name attribute. https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-15/selecting-document-elements ... btw, what link do you have to the web app?

Comment: So far only tested in IE 11 (note that it works in compatability mode, as it does in all other browsers tested on multiple platforms) just not in IE 11 when not in compatabilty mode.

Comment: More like 1995, which when this was written

Comment: What is not valid about it?

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is an element present with ID="H_Documents", the variable H_Documents in the second line is not automagically the reference to that element.

I guess that somewhere in the code there is a construct like:

```
document.addEventListener(....){
   var H_Documents = document.getElementById('H_Documents')
}
```

older versions of IE do not support addEventListener, but instead support document.attachEvent which is more or less the same. I suggest you need to test if addEventListener is available or else switch to attachEvent.

Comment: There's a chance he could have defined the variables outside of the snippet of code he posted?

Comment: I am pretty sure that is the case, since it is working in modern browsers.

Comment: H_documents is defined nowhere else either in the HTML or in the JS.